# Handling laggy input for an allowable length of time

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, input, lag

I have a certain window of time that a user can provide input given some visual feedback.

Under ideal circumstances, they receive this cue and can respond immediately within the allotted time, also if their reaction is slow they can miss it.

But if their system is slow and the input lags, even though they may have responded in time the input won't register till after the window has closed.

I'm looking for suggestions/recommendations on how to handle this dilemma. I would like to manage the input to account for lag and allow valid/on-time input.

The system lag shouldn't be confused with "user lag"

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what system you talk about and where the system lag comes from? Also what platform your program uses?! Maybe a timer would help?

Comment: By system I meant computer lag, but maybe a timer would help.